# Defining a function in terms of a solution returned by Solve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

The title is a little ambiguous, but I didn't know how else to put it. What I'm trying to do is solve a system of equations

```
system1 = 
  {-I*ω*a1 == 
     -I*ω1*a1 - I*J12*a2 - I*J13*a3 - κ1[ω]/2*a1 - γ1[ω]/2*a1 + Sqrt[κ1[ω]]*ain, 
   -I*ω*a2 == -I*ω2*a2 - I*J12*a1 - I*J23*a3 - γ2/2*a2, 
   -I*ω*a3 == -I*ω3*a3 - I*J13*a1 - I*J23*a2 - γ3/2*a3};
```

Which I then solve for a1, a2 and a3:

```
s = Solve[system1, {a1, a2, a3}];
```

And then, finally, I am interested in a function $R(\omega)$ which is given by

```
I*Sqrt[κ1]*(a1 /. s)/ain - 1
```

If I simply use all the above and evaluate that last term, it works. I get a (rather ugly) expression of the type

$\left\{-1+\frac{2 i \text{$\kappa $1} \left(4 \text{J23}^2+(\text{$\gamma $2}-2 i
   (\omega -\text{$\omega $2})) (\text{$\gamma $3}-2 i (\omega -\text{$\omega
   $3}))\right)}{4 \text{J12}^2 (\text{$\gamma $3}-2 i (\omega -\text{$\omega
   $3}))-16 i \text{J12} \text{J13} \text{J23}+4 \text{J13}^2 (\text{$\gamma
   $2}-2 i (\omega -\text{$\omega $2}))+(\text{$\gamma $1}+\text{$\kappa $1}-2 i
   \omega +2 i \text{$\omega $1}) \left(4 \text{J23}^2+(\text{$\gamma $2}-2 i
   \omega +2 i \text{$\omega $2}) (\text{$\gamma $3}-2 i \omega +2 i
   \text{$\omega $3})\right)}\right\}$

(I apologize for the format, I don't know how to give variables and parameters subscripts in mathematica so for example $J_{12}$ comes out as $J12$)

However, I want to define this as a function, and I am not sure if

```
R[ω_] := I*Sqrt[κ1]*(a1 /. s)/ain - 1
```

does the trick.

Now, the real problem comes from the fact that I don't want just this analytic expression, I want to plot $R(\omega)$. The real and imaginary parts, as well as the argument. For this I need values for my constants of course, which is fine. But the problems start appearing when I consider for example $\kappa_1$, which is not a constant but a function. To be clear, every term in these equations, apart from $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$,$\kappa_1$ and $\gamma_1$, are constants. These other five depend on the only variable in the equations, $\omega$.

The main issue is that I don't know how I should do this. I can define for example $\kappa_1$ the way I want to without any problems using

```
κ1[ω_] := 1/(ω*Zc*(C1 + CJ1 + CJ3));
```

This gives me a function $\kappa_1$ that I can evaluate. But how do I put this into my system of equations, system1? Do I have to replace `κ1 with κ1[ω]?`

If I do that, then I run into trouble when solving the system and defining an equation. If anyone coudld help, I'd be very grateful. For completeness, below is the full list of parameters:

```
C1 = 190*10^-15;
C2 = 240*10^-15;
C3  = 270*10^-15;
L1 = 1.74*10^ -9;
L2 = L1;
L3 = L1;
CJ1 = 30*10^-15;
CJ2 = CJ1;
CJ3 = CJ1;
R1 = 2*10^5;
R2 = R1;
R3 = R1;
Zc = 50;
Cmatrix = {{C1 + Cκ, CJ1, CJ3}, {CJ1, C2, CJ2}, {CJ3, CJ2, C3}};
Lmatrix = {{L1, 0, 0}, {0, L1, 0}, {0, 0, L1}};
Linv = Inverse[Lmatrix];
Cinv = Inverse[Cmatrix];
ω1 = Sqrt[Cinv[[1, 1]]*Linv[[1, 1]]];
ω2 = Sqrt[Cinv[[2, 2]]*Linv[[2, 2]]];
ω3 = Sqrt[Cinv[[3, 3]]*Linv[[3, 3]]];
J12 = 0.5*Cinv[[1, 2]]/(Sqrt[Cinv[[1, 1]]]*Cinv[[2, 2]])*Sqrt[ω1*ω2];
J13 = 0.5*Cinv[[1, 3]]/(Sqrt[Cinv[[1, 1]]]*Cinv[[3, 3]])*Sqrt[ω1*ω3];
J23 = 0.5*Cinv[[2, 3]]/(Sqrt[Cinv[[2, 2]]]*Cinv[[3, 3]])*Sqrt[ω3*ω2];
Cκ = 80*10^-15;
γ2 = 1/(R2*(C2 + CJ1 + CJ2));
γ3 = 1/(R3*(C3 + CJ2 + CJ3));
κtilde = 1/(Zc*Cκ);
BigK[ω_] := 1 + (κtilde/ω)^2;
Cκtilde[ω_] := Cκ*(1 - 1/BigK[ω]);
κ1[ω_] := 1/(BigK[ω]*Zc*(C1 + CJ1 + Cκtilde[ω] + CJ3));
γ1[ω_] := 1/(R1*(C1 + CJ1 + CJ3 + Cκtilde[ω]));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but perhaps `R[ω_] = Abs[(a1 /. s)/ain - 1]` is what you want. Note I used `Set`, not `SetDelayed`.

Comment: You are right, it's too vague. I've updated my main post!

Comment: I still can't figure out what `ain` is.

Comment: Right, a product of terrible notation. Its $a_{in}$, a constant value that gets divided out at the end so it doesn't need an actual value. It is in there all the way until I get to $R(\omega)$, then it disappears. Context wise, it has to do with an incoming wave in an electronic circuit containing inductors, resistors and capacitors. I'm calculating the reflection coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your definitions of `system1` and `s`, when I write

```
R[ω_] = Simplify[I*Sqrt[κ1[ω]]*(a1 /. s)/ain - 1][[1]]
```

I get

> ```
> R[ω_] = 
>   -1 + (J13*(4*J23^2 + (γ2 - (2*I)*(ω - ω2))*(γ3 - (2*I)*(ω - ω3)))*κ1[ω])/
>     (4*((J12*J23 + J13*((I/2)*γ2 + ω - ω2))*
>       (-J13^2 + ((I*γ3 + 2*ω - 2*ω3)*(2*ω - 2*ω1 + I*γ1[ω] + I*κ1[ω]))/4) - 
>         ((2*J13*J23 + J12*(I*γ3 + 2*ω - 2*ω3))*(2*J12*J13 + 2*J23*ω - 
>           2*J23*ω1 + I*J23*γ1[ω] + I*J23*κ1[ω]))/4))
> ```

With this definition of `R`, `Re[R[ω]]` ,`Im[R[ω]]`, and `Arg[R[ω]]` all seem eminently plot-able as  functions of `ω`. If this doesn't work for you, you need to tell us what goes wrong.

Please note the use of `Set` ( = ). You don't want to use `SetDelayed` for defining `R`. In this case, the righthand side of the definition needs to be evaluated when the definition is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, with your comment on not using :=, I get to that point. I will actually do a test with a system for which I do know the solution to check if it is not some numerical anomaly instead. The := seems to have ruined a lot..

Comment: Something is definitely still wrong, but I can't figure out what or where. In any case, I've used a different approach now, and that does work. Thanks for your time though, you've answered all that was possible in the current question!